# Hiding the console from D while linked with C-version SDL2

Tags: interop, sdl, linker-errors, d

Basically, I get a console window I don't want to see while writing SDL-windowed applications.

In C, the answer is simple: change your linker SubSystem to Windows; then SDL does the rest. It has a macro that redefines your `main` to `SDL_main`, which it calls from inside its own hidden `WinMain` function. Just make sure you take arguments in your main function and all goes smoothly.

In D, I'm having a little more trouble with it. Upon simply changing the subsystem by passing `-L/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` to the linker, it informs me that I have declared `main`, SDL has declared `WinMain`, and it doesn't know how to deal. I thought changing the signature from `void main()` to `extern(C) int SDL_main(int argc, char*[] argv)` would solve the problem, but then the linker says it can't locate any of D's runtime symbols. Might have something to do with the entry point being written in C?

On the other side, my problem might be with how I have set up Derelict. I am working from [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/cybershadow/derelict), which is a live-updated amalgam of all the different Derelict repositories on GitHub. In my VisualD solution, I have three relevant projects: a home-brewed Derelict project containing the source to SDL2 and the Utilities library, and the C-API SDL2 and SDL2main projects as found [here](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror). I compile and link to all three resulting libraries -- Derelict and SDL2main are static, SDL2 is dynamic. I am less inclined to say this setup is to blame, because it works just fine save the undying console window.

Comment: See [ask], provide a [mcve]. External Links **don't count**

Comment: are you on win32 ?

Comment: @Olaf I see no problem with the question as posted. It is suitably terse, and all (but only) the necessary code is posted. Granted, the [c] tag was probably a poor decision. Clarify?

Comment: So can you just skip the SDL2main library? Sounds like it is the real problem, giving you a WinMain you don't actually want.

Comment: @Abstracttype I am programming on Windows, so yes that's what I'm currently targeting. Ideally, the source is cross-platform though -- which is why I'm using SDL at all.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Well, yes and no. I want the WinMain when compiling on Windows (because that's what hides the console there), but also want the code to be portable. And frankly, I have little experience outside of my Windows bubble and offload most of that to SDL.

Comment: you could have been on (or targeted) win**64** too ! I asked this to answer correctly. (optlink option/def file) since DDMD win32 uses digital mars linker.

Comment: The WinMain actually isn't what hides the console, it is the subsystem command to the linker that does it. When the linker sees a WinMain, it just enables that option automatically. So the answer below should give you a solution: pass the option, skip the WinMain library. If you are are 64 bit btw, pass `-L/subsystem:windows -L/entry:mainCRTStartup`, if on 32 bit, only the `/subsystem` one is needed. Should work...

Comment: @Mako: There is no code at all posted. You might want to read the pages I linkes, too.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe It seems I wasn't clear enough in my question; I'll go back and edit it a bit. I have tried this, and in fact this is what produces the link errors at all. Running it without a set SubSystem compiles and links, it just has the console open. Running it with the Windows SubSystem compiles but does not link.

Comment: @Olaf The only code giving me problems is my entry point. I provided my broken entry point, and possible variations on it which also didn't work. What more code do you suggest I provide? I posit that anything more would be unnecessary, and moreover, distracting.

Comment: Yeah, but did you try it while cutting out that sdlmain library, keeping everything else the same? I'm pretty sure the presence of that library is that is causing the problem, not the subsystem switch.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe It is the problem, but after some floundering attempts to do so, it doesn't seem possible to cut out. I might just bite the bullet and write my own code; Derelict is a bit much to just create a window anyways. (Everything else I'm doing goes straight to a Vulkan renderer.)

Comment: If all you want to do is open a window, my simpledisplay.d might be what you want (actually, simpledisplay is becoming quite a SDL-lite!): https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd simpledisplay.d and color.d. Email me if you wanna talk about it in more detail, maybe we can merge some initial efforts destructionator@gmail.com

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe That seems like a much better solution! I'd certainly contribute some code if it if sorts things when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

In the command line passed to DMD, add the linker option `-L/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`

Comment: Maybe you missed it (I wasn't quite that verbose), but I listed that as one of the things I tried. The linker says SDL is also trying to provide an entry point via `WinMain` in addition to my own `main`.

Comment: I was admittedly unclear. I brushed over it with a "by simply changing the subsystem" and mistakenly assumed that would be enough. The question has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In case you use dub (which i recommend) and gdc, insert the following into your dub.json file:

```
"dflags": ["-Wl,--subsystem,windows"]
```

Comment: I don't use dub (yet), but it looks like that would do the same thing as the `-L/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` flag I am passing to DMD currently.